# How to describe the motion or the animation in this video?

Tags: word-request

I think scientifically it is called **damped oscillation** but maybe some people call it **wiggle**? IDK. There could be a term that best describe it and I don't know it. I don't care if it's scientific, slang, or common but I do care to describe it precisely. Also, should I say **Animation** or  **motion** or maybe **movement**?

The graph shows the animation that I'm talking about but it's better to watch the first few seconds of the video to see how the cube moves.

- Graph:

[image]

- Video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_aByDbtuAI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The movement of the cube certainly fits the word *oscillate*, which NOAD defines as:

> move or swing back and forth at a regular speed

I suppose *wiggle* could be used, too, but I think most native speakers would describe the movement of the cube using the term in the dictionary quoted above:

> *In this video, we will show you how to move an object **back-and-forth**.*

Comment: but this is not a regular speed. The cube stops after a while. Should it be called damped oscillation? or maybe damped back and forth?

Comment: This is a science question rather than English.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I mentioned in the question that I don't care about the scientific term. I just want to know how the average person or people in the street would call it.

Comment: @user2824371 - Informally, I would just say, "The cube **moves back-and-forth** and then **slows down after a while**." The term _dampened oscillation_ might be used in a  physics class, but most people on the street don't use that term – unless they happen to be engineers.